# Get native dynamic library filename extension from Java

Tags: java, dll, cross-platform, shared-libraries, native-code

In Java, is there a way to query what the current platform's dynamic library filename extension(s) are using only the JDK or javax libraries? For example, a defined system property?

As a secondary alternative, is there a third-party Java library out there that does this?

As a tertiary alternative, is the problem so trivial I can easily roll my own (*eg* .dll on Windows, .so everywhere else)?

Comment: On OS X, the extension used is `.dylib`.

Comment: Not sure if this is worth posting a full answer for, but from what I've gathered, Unix operating systems use *.so, OSX uses both *.dylib and *.jnilib, and Windows uses *.dll. Not sure if Android uses the same extension as Unix, or something else. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably get what you are looking for using the following API:

```
System.mapLibraryName("your_library");
```

On Linux the return for this would be "libyour_library.so" and on Windows it would be "your_library.dll".  So if you are only interested in the extension, you could do something like:

```
final String libname = System.mapLibraryName("test");
final String libext = libname.substring(libname.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
```

Answer (score -1):

The "standard" native-interop system for Java is [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna). It's been around for a long time, is well-supported, and pretty much handles most any native-invocation scenario you would want. Of course, it supports loading dynamic libraries too.

You should consider using JNA for your project, or failing that, looking to see how *it* decides what the correct dynamic library extension is.